# How to add products in cart which products are in the CSV file Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to add bulk product to cart using csv file in magento2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate module. In your module controller, write code to read product Sku,Qty and required options(if available) and then add those product by using below code :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
class Post extends Action
{
    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        Product $product) {
            $this->formKey = $formKey;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->product = $product;      
            parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
     { 
        //use your csv code here and put in foreach

        $productId =10;
        $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId, 
                    'qty'   =>1
                );              
        $product = $this->product->load($productId);       
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        $this->cart->save();
     }
}
```